# Outlook VBA Set language of selection

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm try to create a macro to set the language of the selection in an outlook email.

I have little experience in VBA scripting.

I copied the Macro I recorded in Word into my Macro-Table for Outlook (or project, or module, I'm not sure how it is named)

```
Sub SelectionEnglish()
    Selection.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS
    Selection.NoProofing = False
    Application.CheckLanguage = True
End Sub
```

This doesn't work because the Selection object is not available. But I saw another question (which I can't find anymore) where the macro author had a way to use the word-editor inside the outlook macro.

Comment: what do you mean by selection? is it an email? or are you selecting something in the email body?

Comment: Yes, a text selection in the email body

Answer (score 7):

> Yes, a text selection in the email body –  tjb 21 mins ago

Try this (To be run from Outlook VBA) Tried and tested on a newly created email. This code shows how to work with the `Selection` Object

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oMailItm As Object, oInsp As Object, oMailEd As Object
    Dim oWord As Object, rng As Object

    Set oInsp = Application.ActiveInspector

    If oInsp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set oMailItm = oInsp.CurrentItem
        If oInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
            Set oMailEd = oMailItm.GetInspector.WordEditor
            Set oWord = oMailEd.Application

            '~~> Set your selection object here
            Set rng = oWord.Selection

            '~~> This is to check if we are getting the selection object 
            '~~> You may comment this or remove it later.
            MsgBox rng.Text

            With rng
                '
                '~~> Rest of the code
                '
            End With
        End If
    End If

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set oWord = Nothing
    Set oMailEd = Nothing
    Set oMailItm = Nothing
    Set oMailItm = oInsp
End Sub
```