# How to select all text and change spelling language?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

I need to select the entire text in the email I'm typing, and change the spelling language.

The following works in Word but doesn't in Outlook 2013.

I added Microsoft Word 15 Object library, with tools -> references, from the VBA editor window.

```vb
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.LanguageID = wdEnglishUK
Selection.NoProofing = False
Application.CheckLanguage = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods and properties specific to one application's VBA language can't be used in other applications like that.

There is a lot of information out there, try a search for "*Outlook VBA Change Message Body Language*" and variations of that.

## Some resources to get you started:

- Stack Overflow: [Outlook VBA Set language of selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21523826/8112776)
- MSDN: [Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx#Outlook2007ProgrammingCh17_ParsingTextFromAMessageBody) with Outlook/VBA
- MSDN: [MailItem Object (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-object-outlook)
- Stack Overflow: [Display email body of selected email in Outlook as a message box in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262411/8112776)
- MSDN: [Introduction to Outlook VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-outlook)

Comment: Thanks. With the first link you posted, I can get .LanguageID = wdEnglishUK to work, but .NoProofing is not recognised.

Comment: Probably not.  Your question asks how to **`change the spelling language`**.

Comment: NoProofing is perfectly relevant, because setting a language but then enabling NoProofing defies the whole point, as it disable the spell checker. Does any one know of a way to set NoProofing = False in Outlook with VBA?

Comment: @ashleedawg - [Link-only answers are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/367954), and so are "Google this up" answers. Please quote the relevant part from the links in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

NoProofing should work as intended.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Proofing_EnglishUK()

    Dim oMailItm As Object
    Dim oInsp As Object
    Dim oMailEd As Object
    Dim oWord As Object
    Dim Rng As Object

    Set oInsp = ActiveInspector

    If oInsp.currentItem.Class = olMail Then

        Set oMailItm = oInsp.currentItem

        If oInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then

            Set oMailEd = oMailItm.GetInspector.WordEditor
            Set oWord = oMailEd.Application

            Set Rng = oWord.Selection
            Rng.WholeStory

            With Rng

                .LanguageID = wdEnglishUK

                ' This should work as intended
                '.NoProofing = False


                ' ******* temporary *************
                ' Check whether .NoProofing can be set
                '  with a spelling error somewhere in the mail
                .NoProofing = Not .NoProofing
                If .NoProofing = False Then
                    MsgBox "Proofing on. Errors should be found."
                Else
                    MsgBox "Proofing off. The errors will not be found."
                End If
                ' ******* temporary *************

            End With

            oMailItm.Save

        End If

    End If

    Set Rng = Nothing
    Set oWord = Nothing
    Set oMailEd = Nothing
    Set oMailItm = Nothing

End Sub
```